# The clone button wont clone opportunity with products in salesforce classic

Tags: opportunity, product, clone, standard

Hi As per the below document from salesforce

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325215&type=1&mode=1

We have opportunity with products, when we try to clone the clone button did not show drop down to show clone with product option as mentioned in the document . Please see attached,

Thanks,
Sam[image]

Comment: Are your Products and Price Book are in active status?

Comment: @Samir  yes they are active

Answer (score 0):

You have added the wrong button. There is a seperate button named **Clone with Related**. Please add this button and try.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Samir I added the clone with related button to the layout ,but when I save the layout and go to the record it does not show there